# Dropped because of collinearity? Stata

Tags: stata

I have three treatment groups, text_only, text_photo, and text_video.

When I run the following code:

```
regress knowledge text_photo text_video
```

Stata has no issue with perfect collinearity. But when I run:

```
regress knowledge text_photo text_video mother_educ father_educ
```

it drops a variable.

What is going on? 
[image]

Comment: I see no programming question here. Specifically you are likely to have a problem with missing values as Stata not only omits a variable but also cannot find enough non-missing data in 76 observations (119 minus 43) to carry out the second regression. Much better to ask on Statalist where a mix of Stata and statistical issues raises no difficulty. It may be, for example, that one or more of your variables is 1 and missing rather than 1 and 0.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not focused on programming and in any case cannot be answered without access to the dataset in question.